# Is there any way to join equal tables in the same Model and in the same Controller?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I’ve done an ASP.NET Web Application project and I have added two ADO.NET Entity Data Model elements from Database with their corresponding Controller.

The fact is that both Database contain the same tables, with the same structure, but with different data. For example, in both Database there is this Table:

```
public partial class User
{
    public long id { get; set; } // Autoincrement
    public string bd { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public short role { get; set; }
}
```

Having only 2, the redundancy when using 2 Models and 2 Controller, was not a big problem, but now I want to add more Databases with the same characteristics (a User table with the same structure, but different data)

Is there any way for all tables to join and have a single Controller? And, in addition, the Controller would allow me to do:

•GET all: get all the data from all the User tables

•GET /id/bd: get the data with id and bd passed in the url

•POST: add a new User in the Database stored in the bd attribute

•PUT / id : modify the data with id and Database stored in the bd attribute

Comment: This doesn't sound like a great idea, but it's possible.You'd need the web config to contain the different connection strings and implement different DbContexts, but using the same controller is slightly ambiguous. You'd also need to have different routes, etc.

Comment: ASP.NET Web API is a web stack. It has nothing to do with data access. Why ask about controllers and HTTP verbs? All you'd need for what you ask would be to use a different connection string in the Entity Framework context

Comment: What are you really asking? How to connect to a different database? Or how to connect to different databases in the same request? Are you creating a multi-tenant application perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, but I’ve been able to solve it in another way.

I’ve stored the different Databases in a Dictionary with Key the name of the Database and value a dynamic type. In this way, instead of calling the object of the Database, I call the dynamic of the Dictionary stored in the Database passed by parameter in the request. In this way, I can add more Databases just by adding one more element to the Dictionary, saving me a lot of redundant code.

To give an example of the change, I show you the Get /id /bd method of before and now:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    // Before
    private typeDB1 db = new typedb1();
    private typeDB2 db2 = new typedb2();

    [ResponseType(typeof(User))]
    [Route("api/users/{id}/{bdatos}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUser(long id, string bdatos)
    {
        try
        {
            if(bdatos == "typeDB1")
            {
                typeDB1.User userdb1 = typeDB1.Find(id);
                if (userdb1 == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                return Ok(userdb1);
            }
            else
            {
                typeDB2.User userdb2 = typeDB2.Find(id);
                if (userdb2 == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                return Ok(userdb2);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    // Now
    private typeDB1 db = new typedb1();
    private typeDB2 db2 = new typedb2();

    private Dictionary<string, dynamic> dbDictionary = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>
    {
        ("typeDB1", db),
        ("typeDB2", db2)
    };

    [ResponseType(typeof(User))]
    [Route("api/users/{id}/{bdatos}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUser(long id, string bdatos)
    {
        try
        {
            dynamic certificate = dbDictionary[bdatos].Find(id);
            if (certificate == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(certificate);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, if all your tables are the same then you don't need multiple redundant models, you can just use one. this takes care of one side of the issue.

another thing you could do is store a list of connection strings, assign a unique identifier to each one and access them all via one controller. you would only require an extra parameter in your routes to specify which database you want to work with. So you're now down to one User model and one controller with whatever methods you need and you don't need to implement the same thing repeatedly.

your routes could look like api/client1/users for example. client1 identifier tells you which database you need to connect to.

There are of course other considerations like maybe you need to expose this to the outside world. in that case you could use a JWT authorization system, you issue each client with a ClientID and then based on the ClientID you know which database to connect to. If you use such a system, then you don't need to pass any extra data in the URL, you issue a token, you add a claim stating which database to use and you're done.

Answer (score -1):

You could use AutoMapper to map the User data models (from different databases) to an User object which you use in your controller.